# Is it possible to apply a custom font to all elements in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Like the question says, i want to know if there is a way to apply a custom font to all elements in QML like we can easily do in HTML setting the font on the tag body.
I already have the font accessible in QML with:

```
FontLoader { id: robotoRegular; source: "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" }
```

But now if i do something like

```
ApplicationWindow {
font.family:robotoRegular.name
```

It doesn't seem to work, and probably isnt supposed to.
Or is there a way?

Im using Qt 5.11.2, QtQuick 2.2

Comment: According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html it should work on Text items. It doesn't seem ApplicationWindow has a font property at all.

Comment: I have to set individually all elements?

Comment: You can either set font for the window(and for the all its control) using [ApplicationWindow.font](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#font-prop) or for the application using [QGuiApplication::setFont](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qguiapplication.html#setFont).

Comment: ```font:robotoRegular``` like this? still doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include <QFontDatabase>

void InstallDefaultFont()
{
    qint32 fontId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/font.otf");
    QStringList fontList = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(fontId);

    QString family = fontList.first();
    QGuiApplication::setFont(QFont(family));
}
```

This will setup the default font for QML and Widgets as well.

Comment: this line ```QString &family = arrFontList.at(0);``` gives error

Comment: sorry, different variable name. It should be ok, now

Comment: This seems to work now, and aswers my question thanks! the only drawback is that if i want to define another font to elements it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing C++, you can use just QML:

```
FontLoader {
    id: localFontRegular
    source: "qrc:/font/SourceHanSansCN-Regular.otf"
}

Text {
    id: name
    text: qsTr("text")
    font.family: localFontRegular.font.family
    font.weight: localFontRegular.font.weight
}
```

Comment: I use .ttf file change `localFontRegular.font.family` to `localFontRegular.name` work for me.